# Values Cannot be Converted to JSON Array

Tags: java, android

This is the function that's giving me the problem:

```
    public String URLToJson() {
    String result = "";
    String jsonString = ReadingURL(" here goes my URL that reads a JSON ");
    JSONObject jsonResult = null;
    try {
        jsonResult = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray data = jsonResult.getJSONArray("Configuracion");
        if (data != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= data.length(); i++) {
                result =  result + "Dirección: " + data.getJSONObject(i).getString("Direccion") + "\n";
                result =  result + "Cédula: " + data.getJSONObject(i).getString("Cedula") + "\n";
                result =  result + "Nombre: : " + data.getJSONObject(i).getString("Nombre") + "\n";
                result =  result + "Teléfono : " + data.getJSONObject(i).getString("Telefono") + "\n";
                result =  result + "Hacienda: " + data.getJSONObject(i).getString("Hacienda") + "\n";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error Reading JSON Data";
    }
}
```

And then this comes up:

```
`W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"Direccion":"Somewhere","Cedula":"111111","Nombre":"Something","Telefono":"2222-2440","Hacienda":"Something"} at Configuracion of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:588)
        at com.example.user.mypos.PrintManager.URLToJson(PrintManager.java:977)
W/System.err:     at com.example.user.mypos.PrintManager$4.run(PrintManager.java:917)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value { the values that are supposed to be }  of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`
```

ReadingURL basically reads the content of an URL, that has the JSON in String.

Comment: Could you post the whole stack trace? All I can think of is this line `JSONArray data = jsonResult.getJSONArray("Configuracion");` it might be that in jsonResult the *Configuracion* is a JSONObject and not JSONArray

Comment: Please post a sample of the JSON response.

Comment: Check the edited question, there's the full stacktrace

Comment: This line `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"Direccion":"Somewhere","Cedula":"111111","Nombre":"Something","Telefono":"2222-2440","Hacienda":"Something"} at Configuracion of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)` says the *Configuracion* is not a JSONArray is a JSONObject. Change this line `JSONArray data = jsonResult.getJSONArray("Configuracion");` to this `JSONObject data = jsonResult.getJSONObject("Configuracion");` and instead of the for loop get the details one by one from the *data* instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exception it's clear that the **JSON string returned by the URL is of type JSONObject not of JSONArray** .

> Value { the values that are supposed to be } of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

JSON object will starts  with { & ends with }

> {
>        "KEY1":"VALUE1",
>        "KEY2":"VALUE2"
>      }

and JSON array will starts with [ and ends with ] .

> [
>      {"KEY1":"VALUE1","KEY2":"VALUE2"},{"KEY1":"VALUE1","KEY2":"VALUE2"}
>   ]

So you are getting this exception because you are trying to convert JSON object to JSON array.

Comment: Ok i changed it so that there's no longer an array, just an object and now it doesn't recognize the data

Comment: Now you are trying to parse variable **jsonResult** or **data** ?

Comment: Look at the answer below, i explained it more thoroughly

Comment: Can you print the **jsonResult** variable  as a string and check the data in it. Using jsonResult.toString();

Comment: I think the key you are passing to the Json Object's **jsonResult.get("Direccion")**  method may be wrong one

Comment: it just prints the whole json

Comment: Can you share that here ?

Comment: You're right the key is Configuracion, which i deleted when i deleted the array, how can i access the field "Direccion" with the "Configuracion" key?

Comment: If you get **Configuration** it will return another JSONObject. Print that and See. You will get idea :)

Comment: JSONObject jsonConfig= jsonResult.get("configuracion");

Comment: Thanks, you were a great help

Comment: Welcome :) @Sarcastic Hawke

Answer (score 0):

to Deepak Gunasekaran

```
public String URLToJson() {
    String result = "";
    String jsonString = ReadingURL("http://deliciasmarinas.avancari.co.cr/app/tiquete.php?factura=414696772");
    JSONObject jsonResult = null;
    try {
        jsonResult = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            for (int i = 0; i <= jsonResult.length(); i++) {
                result =  result + "Dirección: " + jsonResult.get("Direccion") + "\n";
                result =  result + "Cédula: " + jsonResult.get("Cedula") + "\n";
                result =  result + "Nombre: : " + jsonResult.get("Nombre") + "\n";
                result =  result + "Teléfono : " + jsonResult.get("Telefono") + "\n";
                result =  result + "Hacienda: " + jsonResult.get("Hacienda") + "\n";
            }
        return result;
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error Reading JSON Data";
    }
}
```

And now it just shows

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for Direccion
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at com.example.user.mypos.PrintManager.URLToJson(PrintManager.java:978)
        at com.example.user.mypos.PrintManager$4.run(PrintManager.java:917)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```